# Percents off by one pixel in Webkit

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have two `div`-elements, the top one has the height of **40%** and the other one **60%**.
In my example I have positioned the first one to `top: 0;` and the second one to `bottom: 0;`. My issue is that I get a 1px distance between them in Webkit, sometimes!

I have created a jsFiddle that recreates the issue in Webkit (Safari and Chrome, but works fine in Firefox.)

http://jsfiddle.net/bVxDA/ (Resize the window to see the bug in action)

This is the code I'm using.

HTML

```
<div id="cover-top"></div>
<div id="cover-bottom"></div>​
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
}

#cover-top,
#cover-bottom {
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}

#cover-top {
    height: 40%;
    top: 0;
}

#cover-bottom {
    height: 60%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

​
I would be fine with a solution that uses JavaScript or jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the height of `html, body` height is an odd number there is a 1px line "remainder".

Webkit can't divide 1px and doesn't try.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/gPu3Y/

You could make the 1px line disappear if you set the following:

```
#cover-bottom {
    height: auto;
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this happens every time 40% isn't a whole number. lets assume your page is 98px height, so we get:

- 40% = 39,2px
- 60% = 58,8px

since we can't draw "half" pixels, the first div gets a height of 39px and the second one gets 58px. also, the second one is drawn 40px from above because both divs can't "overlap" (remember: the first one is 39,2px heigh, so we can't start drawing at 39px - there would be 0.2px overlapping) - and so we end up with this very weird "gap" between them.

Answer (score 0):

just change last rule in

```
#cover-bottom {
    top: 40%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

​
so it doesn't matters if the height of the `<html>` element is odd

http://jsfiddle.net/bVxDA/4/ (I changed background colour just to check the fill behaviour)